# Where is the shared folder in Remmina?

Tags: remote-desktop

I've been searching for the past couple of hours with no solution in sight. I'm using Remmina to RDP into a Windows XP machine, and have a shared folder set under `/home/RDP_Shared`.

I don't see this anywhere in the machine I'm connecting to. I've searched high and low, in many of the C: folders, in the Network folders, in everything. I have sound set to local. I can't find any Remmina manuals, documentation, or anything.

Answer (score 13):

As mentioned above, it's working for me with Remmina 1.2. The shared folder is available at `\\tsclient\<SHARED_FOLDER_NAME>` (in case it saves anyone any time looking for it).

Answer (score 9):

In older versions of remmina there were some [bugs](https://github.com/FreeRDP/Remmina/issues/243), please ensure that you have recent version (like 1.2.X).

You may want to use remmina-next to get it:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:remmina-ppa-team/remmina-next
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libfreerdp-plugins-standard remmina remmina-plugin-rdp
```

Comment: Remmina 1.1.2 ships with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and is not able to share folders with Windows 2016. Following these steps resulted in Remmina 1.2 and shared folders now work. Thank you!

Comment: Also with Ubuntu 18.04 this problem persists with Remmina 1.2.0 and is fixed with this approach :+1: